# Display output after pattern matching

Tags: php, linux, centos

I am creating a php script which I need to import some values to variables and I am stuck in one variable.

```
$data[7]='/47/NSW/5643256'

I want $data[7]='5643256'
```

How can I Pattern match '/' and print the 2nd matched pattern? Tried with `awk` didn't work :(

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry Sweety, cant you clarify what you want?

Comment: Is it `php` or `bash`?

Comment: if its a PHP then you can do `$data[7]= end(explode('/',$data[7]));`

Comment: @Allan: Its php

Comment: @Ash-b :  Awesome ash. It worked.Thats exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if you want `php` or `shell` script but

If what you want is a script that will be triggered by your php code you can use one of the solutions hereunder using `cut`, `grep`, `awk`, `sed`:

```
echo '/47/NSW/5643256' | rev | cut -f-1 -d'/' | rev                                                                            
5643256

echo '/47/NSW/5643256' | grep -oE '[0-9]+$'
5643256

echo '/47/NSW/5643256' | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'                                                                               
5643256

echo '/47/NSW/5643256' | sed 's@.*/\([0-9]\+\)$@\1@'
5643256
```

If what you want is `php` then you have several solutions:

```
$data[7]='/47/NSW/5643256'
$data[7]=preg_replace(".*\/([0-9]+)$", '\1', $data[7]);
```

or

```
$data[7]= end(explode('/',$data[7]));
```

or

```
preg_match('(?<=\/)([0-9]+)$', $data[7], $m );
$data[7]=$m[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on pattern matching you can do it via [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function. Like so:

```
preg_match("/\/\d+\/\w+\/(\d+)/", $data[7], $output);
// $output[1] == 5643256, hence we can reassign
$data[7] = $output[1];
```

I've constructed the regex with assumption that your data is formatted in similar fashion as your example.

But if you don't need to use regex pattern matching, I'd use this:

```
$data[7]= end(explode('/',$data[7]));
```

as @Ash-b suggested in comment section.